# How to load images with relative path in image control?

Tags: relative-path

I have a c# program in which it need to load a main image and its thumbnail in image control for which I need to use their relative path. All the main images are stored in a folder "images" and their thumbnails are stored in a sub-folder "thumbs". And, all the thumbnails have exact same name as the main images. I know how to give relative path for a specific file but I don't know how to give relative path for dynamic file. In other words, how do I give the dynamic filename for both main image and its thumbnail image holder? i.e. instead of xyz.jpg, there can many other image name, how do i do it?

```
    <div>
        <img id="ProductMain" src="\Business\images\xyz.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:150px;height:100px;">
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><img class="thumbnail" src="\Business\images\thumbs\xyz.jpg" alt="Img1" style="width:30px;height:25px;"></td>
          </tr>                          
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: When using path, prepend it with ~
src="~\Business\images\xyz.jpg"

Comment: And how is this related to c#??

Comment: I'm guessing you're setting the source for these images in c#?  If so, you could concatenate the string together based on whatever the dynamic criteria are and then set the source equal to the concatenates file path string.

Comment: Please attempt to add more detail, such as your code where you are gathering information about your path, such as the image name, and image extension. Also, a simple google search can tell you numerous ways of creating relative paths. I would also recommend ALWAYS starting from the root of your website, like @Reddy suggested. In your case, it would be `~/Business/images/path/imageFileName.fileExt`